# Delete cookies in Firefox after specific interval of time

Tags: firefox, cookies, firefox-extensions

Is there any Firefox addon which will delete my all cookies after specific interval of time.

I do not want to block any site's cookie; I just want all the cookies to be deleted after every 30 seconds or 60 seconds.

Can it be done ?

Regards

Comment: Are you sure? ;) http://i.imgur.com/xoq5c.jpg

Comment: That was funny Mehper...But i know how to delete cookies... :-) I just want any automted process to make it easy,,,,if there is no such addon i will create one for myself  :-)

Comment: Fun is good. I have examined the addons list page but couldn't find what you exactly need; but I might have overlooked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default firefox can be set to delete cookies after a set time, but it can only be set by number of days, if that is of use to you then you can do this.

Go to about:config

```
Set network.cookie.lifetimePolicyto to 3
```

and

```
network.cookie.lifetime.days to 1
```

You could also set

```
network.cookie.lifetimePolicy to 2 if you only want them to last the browser session
```

If you install and setup CCleaner to erase cookies you could also run it on a scheduled task with

```
CCleaner.exe /AUTO
```

Comment: @Thanks..for the info..That was useful but still not complete answer..i will serch more and if i dont get any thing like it..will accept ur answer.

Comment: It seems these don't exist anymore in my default config. ANyone know if they still work when added or have this been removed?

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for that too. What I have found so far:

- Manually deleting cookies via settings in "Clear recent history" or via Options, Privacy, Cookie Settings
- Automatically deleting flash-cookies with the [BetterPrivacy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/betterprivacy/) AddOn
- AddOns for Cookie-management in Firefox to be checked out:

  - [Cookie Culler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookieculler/)
  - [Cookie Monster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-monster/)
  - [Extended Cookie Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/extended-cookie-manager/)
  - [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) + [FireCookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/)

---

I haven't found an add-on that gives you the choice setting of e.g. deleting all cookies every 10 seconds, or even that with white- and black-list exceptions.

The above `about:config` with e.g. 0.01 days or so doesn't work. Only full days.

In any case, I recommend using AddBlock+, NoScript, FlashBlock, BetterPrivacy, Ghostery, googleSharing, HTTPS-everywhere and maybe even still TrackMeNot. 
LongURLplease, WebDeveloper, FireBug and GreaseMonkey are fruther usefull AddOns.

Also you might want to look into MAFIAAfire, Gee!NoEvil! ThePirateBayDancing and/or DeSOPA.

Comment: Please register your account with Super User, then you can edit your posts any time!

Comment: Yeh, there is no addon which allows automation of cookie deletion after specific interval of time.

Answer (score 0):

One useful utility is called `BetterPrivacy` and can do exactly this for Flash cookies.  It doesn't do the regular cookie side of things though.

Answer (score 0):

Try Cookie Time, an addon for mozilla firefox.

With some editing in its files (bootstrap.js, cookietime.dtd and options.xul) options can be added for even less than a day. Maybe that will help. Unedited, the shortest time period is a day.

Also, Self-destruct Cookies addon should help some if it is what you want. Also for firefox